# Get discord member's roles by ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am looking to get the id of every role a user has. the user being the message author in my case.

i've tried various things suggested such as `let roles = message.author.roles.id = []` and `message.guild.roles.fetch()` however nether seem to do what I need.

```js
var XPRole = {};
if (fs.existsSync('noxprole.json')) {
   XPRole = jsonfile.readFileSync('noxprole.json');
}
client.on('message', async (message) => {
    const { member } = message;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    

    if (message.guild.id in XPRole === false) {
       XPRole[message.guild.id] = {};
    }
    const RoleID = XPRole[message.guild.id];
    if ('...' in RoleID) {
       return;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

The intention of this code is to compare a users roles against a JSON file containing a list of roles that wont earn xp when typing.

Comment: `message.author` returns a **User** Object, which is a global Discord User which has no roles. `message.member.roles.cache` will return the Collection of roles a member has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Elitezen mentioned in their comment, `message.author` is a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) and Users don't have roles, only GuildMembers. You also can't use `message.guild.roles` as it returns a manager of the roles belonging to this guild, not just those belonging to the member.

You can however get the author of a message as a guild member by using the [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) property. Now, that you have the member, you can get the roles of them by accessing the member's [`roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles). As the `roles` property returns a [manager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager), you need to access its `cache` property:

```js
const roles = message.member.roles.cache;
```

It returns a collection of the roles of this member, and collections have a [`.map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) method that maps each item to another value into an array. It means that you can easily create an array of role IDs this member has using `roles.map`:

```js
const memberRoleIDs = roles.map((role) => role.id);
// => ['772088200214723861', '809320713752256548', '8184301957544091683']
```

As you can see, `memberRoleIDs` contains all the role IDs the member has.

I'm not sure how you store the role IDs in `XPRole[message.guild.id]`. It seems you store it as an object and the IDs are the keys. In that case, you can use the [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method that tests if at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the callback function.

So, if your `XPRole[message.guild.id]` object with IDs as keys, you can simply compare these keys to the array of role IDs. Check and run the following snippet:

```js
let message = {
  guild: {
    id: 'guildID'
  }
}
const memberRoleIDs = [
  '7720882002147238612',
  '8093207137522565483',
  '8093207137522565481'
];
let XPRole = {
  'guildID': {
    '7437501734702175013': { /**** */ },
    '8093207137522565481': { /**** */ },
    '9483513543347850432': { /**** */ },
  }
}

const containsRole = memberRoleIDs.some(id => id in XPRole[message.guild.id]);

// returns true as 8093207137522565481 is in both
console.log({ containsRole });
```

If you instead store an array of role IDs like in the following example, you can still use the same `some()` method but with a different callback, one that checks if any of the user role IDs is included in your `XPRole[message.guild.id]` array:

```js
let message = {
  guild: {
    id: 'guildID'
  }
}
const memberRoleIDs = [
  '7720882002147238612',
  '8093207137522565483',
  '8093207137522565481'
];
let XPRole = {
  'guildID': [
    '7437501734702175013',
    '8093207137522565481',
    '9483513543347850432',
  ]
}

const containsRole = memberRoleIDs.some(id => XPRole[message.guild.id].includes(id));

// returns true as 8093207137522565481 is in both
console.log({ containsRole });
```

**Here is the full code:**

```js
let XPRole = {};
if (fs.existsSync('noxprole.json')) {
  XPRole = jsonfile.readFileSync('noxprole.json');
}

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const roles = message.member.roles.cache;
  const memberRoleIDs = roles.map((role) => role.id);

  if (message.guild.id in XPRole === false) {
    XPRole[message.guild.id] = {};
  }

  if (memberRoleIDs.some((id) => id in XPRole[message.guild.id])) {
    return console.log('member has at least one role id included in XPRole');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all the roles of the member. So you will need to collect the [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object instead of the [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User).

```js
const RoleID = XPRole[message.guild.id];

for(var memberRoleID in message.member.roles.cache.array()) {
  if (RoleID.includes(message.member.roles.cache.array()[memberRoleID].id)) {
    return;
  }
}
```